# Can cat be used to clone a partition?

Tags: linux, bash, clone, dd, cat

For example, can I do:

```
cat /dev/sda1 > /dev/sda2
```

instead of using dd, and if not, why will this not work?

Comment: You should be able to do this using `cat`, `cp`, `dd` and a dozen other tools.  dd has the advantage that you can specify a block size which can speed things up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In principle, you could use either. There are few important differences, but none that apply here.

- When you use `>` redirection, the target file is opened, and truncated. Only then it is written to. However this does not apply to block devices — they have a fixed size, so “truncation” doesn't do anything to them.
- With `cat` you can not easily tell it to only copy the first *n* bytes or skip/seek. [This is what `dd` is useful for](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/dd-vs-cat-is-dd-still-relevant-these-days/12538#12538).
- `cat` does not let you specify a block size. This won't matter today when block sizes are masked by the file systems being used, but it used to make a difference where devices would be read from with specific block sizes (tapes).
- For hard disks, [`cat` may be slightly faster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd/9492#9492) (better even than `dd` with a well-chosen block size, let alone the default which slows things down).

Comment: That is an excellent post you linked to.