# Cannot boot from any device after attempted drive clone with `cat`

Tags: boot, bios, ubuntu-16.04, disk-cloning

I was attempting to clone a drive from a 120GB SSD containing Ubuntu 16.04 to a 1TB SSD using `cat` as I'd read it was generally faster than `dd`. After taking a suspiciously short time to finish (~20 minutes), I rebooted to check if it had worked. To my surprise, neither drive could be booted from anymore, even though the BIOS sees both SATA drives.

I tried making a bootable USB with both UNetbootin (containing a live Ubuntu) and Rufus (containing tools for reflashing BIOS). However I was still not able to boot from the USB. (I checked on another computer that at least the Rufus USB was bootable, which was successful.)

The only boot option that I see anymore is `Realtek PXE B03 D00`. But even booting from this just prompts me to insert a bootable media, which doesn't work.

**Update:** Got bootable usb to work, seems like problem was usb 3.0 port. Somehow a different port worked, maybe because it was a combo 3.0/eSATA and that helped(?). After booting to live Ubuntu usb, I was able to mount and recover my data from the unbootable source drive. After that, the drive (automagically) was able to boot into "`emergency mode`", but I just went ahead with a clean reinstall from there.

Remaining question: why did `cat` disrupt boot-ability on source drive? Maybe overwrote something in BIOS? (At least four SU and unix.SE questions seem to indicate `cat` is just fine or even preferred for copy/cloning: [su](https://superuser.com/questions/692588/can-cat-be-used-to-clone-a-partition), [se1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224277/is-it-better-to-use-cat-dd-pv-or-another-procedure-to-copy-a-cd-dvd), [se2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/dd-vs-cat-is-dd-still-relevant-these-days), [se3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144172/full-dd-copy-from-hdd-to-hdd).)

Comment: Did you clone in the wrong direction, i.e. overwrite the master disk with the empty new disk?

Comment: Nope (double checked about 8 times). Plus Ubuntu was still functional before I rebooted. And wouldn't explain not being able to boot from usb?

Comment: Also if it matters, target drive may not have been empty. Likely there was a Win10 install on it. (Though I was told it was `shred`ed, but didn't verify.)

Comment: **cat** is not meant to be used with binary data.  Check the boot order in your BIOS to see if that got changed.

Comment: Boot order is same, but booting from drives fails: prompts `Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key` ad nauseam. This is even with verified bootable usb inserted (which does not appear anywhere in BIOS).

Comment: @cybernard that seems like a bit of a bizarre statement. do you have any documentation to support that claim?